# client.send_file sending image as 0 bytes discord py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Whenever the  `await client.send_file(client.get_channel('491846919262437377'), 'jackpotpapi2.png')` hits, a file with 0 bytes is sent to the channel instead of the actual image. The file size is around 52kb and fairly small. The image that sends at the end shows up with no problem (`await client.send_file(client.get_channel('491846919262437377'), 'jackpotpapi.png')`)

```
elif slot1 == '<:papii:492030512760750090>' and slot2 == '<:papii:492030512760750090>' and slot3 == '<:papii:492030512760750090>':
    await client.edit_message(mtg, "\t{}".format(slotOutput))
    await client.send_file(client.get_channel('491846919262437377'), 'slots2.png')
    await client.send_message(message.channel, " {} hit 3 <:papii:492030512760750090>'s for $800! ".format(message.author.mention))
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "{} moves onto the bonus round for a chance to win the jackpot!".format(message.author.mention))
    add_dollars(message.author, 800)
    remove_dollars(message.author, 10)

    #JACKPOT BONUS ROUND

    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    await client.send_file(client.get_channel('491846919262437377'), 'jackpotpapi2.png')
    jck = await client.send_message(message.channel, "{}".format(jackOutput))
    await client.edit_message(jck, "{}".format(animationjack))
    await client.edit_message(jck, "{}".format(animationjack2))
    await client.edit_message(jck, "{}".format(animationjack3))
    if jack1 == '' and jack2 == '' and jack3 == '' and jack4 == '' and jack5 == '':
        await client.edit_message(jck, "{}".format(jackOutput)) 
        await client.send_file(client.get_channel('491846919262437377'), 'jackpotpapi.png')
        await client.send_message(message.channel, " CONGRATS {}! You've hit 5 's for an additional $1000! ".format(message.author.mention))
        add_dollars(message.author, 1000)
    elif jack1 == '' and jack2 == '' and jack3 == '' and jack4 == '' and jack5 == '':
        await client.edit_message(jck, "{}".format(jackOutput)) 
        await client.send_file(client.get_channel('491846919262437377'), 'jackpotpapi.png')
        await client.send_message(message.channel, " CONGRATS {}! You've hit 5 's for an additional $1250! ".format(message.author.mention))
        add_dollars(message.author, 1250)
    elif jack1 == '<:papi:492025149525327902>' and jack2 == '<:papi:492025149525327902>' and jack3 == '<:papi:492025149525327902>' and jack4 == '<:papi:492025149525327902>' and jack5 == '<:papi:492025149525327902>':
        await client.edit_message(jck, "{}".format(jackOutput)) 
        await client.send_file(client.get_channel('491846919262437377'), 'jackpotpapi.png')
        await client.send_message(message.channel, " CONGRATS {}! YOU'VE WON THE JACKPOT FOR AN ADDITIONAL $2000! ".format(message.author.mention))
        add_dollars(message.author, 2000)
    else:
        await client.edit_message(jck, "{}".format(jackOutput)) 
        await client.send_file(client.get_channel('491846919262437377'), 'jackpotpapi.png')
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "Better luck next time {}!".format(message.author.mention))
```

Comment: "The image that sends at the end shows up with no problem" I'm confused.   Does sending the image succeed or fail?  You send other files using this method, do they succeed?  Have you tried `open`ing the file (in `rb` mode) and passing that as your file pointer instead?

Comment: The actual send is successful, it's just that after it's sent, it only shows up as a "box" that says the filename and 0 bytes next to it. I am sending other images with this same method (towards the bottom of the current code) and I'm not having any issues with it. I'll try to use the rb method to see if that will change anything